# How to declare generic function inside protocol

Tags: ios, swift, function, protocols, generic-programming

This is my code

```
protocol sharedFunction {

      func transformDictionary<Element>(postDictionary:[Element:Element], key: Element) -> Element


}


class newUser: sharedFunction {

var email:String?
var username:String?
var uid: String?

func transformDictionary(postDictionary: [String : Any], key: String) -> newUser {

 }
}
```

But I keep on getting this error "Type newUser" does not conform to protocol" "sharedFunction"

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs simply because your type do not conform to the protocol as the message clearly states. I'd rewrite your code like this:

```
protocol SharedFunction {
    associatedtype Element: Hashable
    func transformDictionary(postDictionary: [Element:Element], key: Element) -> Element
}

class NewUser: SharedFunction {

    typealias Element = Int

    var email: String?
    var username: String?
    var uid: String?

    func transformDictionary(postDictionary: [Element : Element], key: Element) -> Element {
        return 1
    }

}
```

I have no ideia what is the context of this code so I don't know if my code makes sense for you but I think you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Change your protocol declaration as

```
protocol sharedFunction {

      func transformDictionary<Element>(postDictionary:[Element: Any], key: Element) -> Any

}
```

You are not following your protocol declaration in your class. That is the reason for error.

Comment: But I want to return something in the function

Comment: Yes, this should work. Did you try replacing your protocol with my code above? What is the error message? It is returning "Any" as shown in my code.